# Weird python syntax error with variable

Tags: python

I keep getting a syntax error on line 10 that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    user = input("Choose a number")
  File "<string>", line 1
    python main.py
              ^
```

I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
import random 

number = random.randint(1, 20)
attempt = 5
def game():
    global attempt
    attempt -= 1
    if attempt > 0:
        if int(user) > number:
            user = input("Choose a number")
            print("Choose a smaller number\n  " + (str(attempt) + " tries left"))
            game()
        elif int(user) < number:
            print("Choose a larger number\n "+ (str(attempt) + " tries left"))
            game()
        elif int(user) == number:
            print ("You guessed the number ")
    else: 
        print("CONGRATULATIONS ")
game()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, this is a run-time error, not a syntax error.

The problem is actually in the previous line: you've tried to use the value of `user` before it has one.  You have to fix this before you can continue debugging your program.  You need to get the user's first number before you can test it.

Comment: even if I switch the 2 lines
        if int(user) > number:
            user = input("Choose a number")
it still gives me the same error

Comment: Is the traceback in the original question the full text of the error? When I switch those two lines it runs. It's possible something else is going wrong.

Comment: yes the traceback is the error @JoshKarpel

Comment: BTW, you never actually showed the error, just the traceback.  There's one more line that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

> **Problem A**

I can't help but notice that your traceback message doesn't align with the code you have provided. It seems as though you already have the `user` variable assigned before defining and calling the `game()` function.

> **Solution A**

If that is the case, try removing that line and apply the changes **Prune** recommended for you in the other answer. This will solve the code related problems in the program.

> **Problem B**

However, the traceback also mentions that on line 1 you have `python main.py`. This is most likely caused by the way you are running the script.

> **Solution B**

Try running it instead in the **IDLE** (distributed with Python) or **Terminal / Command Prompt** (depends on your OS) if not doing so already.

> **Last Resort**

If the problem still arises, try running the snippet of code you included in the question by itself to see if it is functional ( add on **Prune's** revisions with it ).

Since the revised snippet should work, any errors that occur is definitely caused by how the code is ran. If no errors occur then look through your original source code for anything else that might be causing problems.

*Good luck!*